# How to Binding Image From ViewModel Without Listview On Xamarin

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

i create model that has 3 data which is id, name , image

```
public class PromoB
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
}
```

and this data is obtained from HttpGetMethod , i'm able to get the data and binding it to my listview. But i'm still confused when i want just to select the image and bind it to my Image Source. I try Bind my ImageSource to PromoB (my model) but the image not shows up. here is my viewmodel right now

```
private ObservableCollection<PromoB> promo;
public ObservableCollection<PromoB> Promo
{
    get { return promo; }
    set { promo = value; }
}

public PromoViewModel()
{
    // Here you can have your data form db or something else,
    // some data that you already have to put in the list

    Promo = new ObservableCollection<PromoB>();

    // Web service call to update list with new values  

    MyHTTP.GetPromoB(list =>
    {
        foreach (PromoB item in list)
            Promo.Add(item);
    });
}
```

and my Task to get the Data

```
public static async Task GetPromoB(Action<IEnumerable<PromoB>> action)
{
    string sUrl = "myurl";
    string sContentType = "application/json"; // or application/xml

    HttpClient oHttpClient = new HttpClient();
    var oTaskPostAsync = await oHttpClient.GetAsync(sUrl);
    if (oTaskPostAsync.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string content = await oTaskPostAsync.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        List<PromoB> o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PromoB>>(content);
        action(o);
    }
}
```

and i try to binding the data in my view like this

```
<Image Source="{Binding Promo}" HeightRequest="167" />
```

so how exactly i should bind the data to my ImageSource because in listview first i bind mylistview to PromoB and  then i bind ImageSource using image bind label using name. Im still not familiar with viewmodel . Your answer will very helpfull to me thanks

here is my full Xaml

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0">
    <Image Source="{Binding Promo}" 
           HeightRequest="167" />   
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: What is PromoDB.image? Is it a URL?

Comment: Yes my PromoDb.image is a url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind Image to URL Xamarin Forms XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579372/bind-image-to-url-xamarin-forms-xaml)

Comment: @EvZ so how exactly i get the image ? with this public Uri ProductImage { get; set; }  ? and then what ?  but my Task is deserialze to PromoB model

Comment: Supposing you've set your listview's ItemSourcee as "Promo":
<Image Source="{Binding image}" HeightRequest="167" />

Comment: @Vahid thats the probelm my image dont use Listview  it make me confused what should i bind to my imagesource, anysugestion ?

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang "my image dont use Listview" what does it mean? Can you post your full XAML?

Comment: i'm update my question as you can see, in the top of my listview i want to add One big Image that obtained from HttmGetMethod

Answer (score 0):

1. Given `Items` is of `ObservableCollection<PromoB>` **only** use `FlowItemsSource = {Binding Items}`.. You're using the default `ItemsSource` aswell.
2. Make sure the `BindingContext` is of type `PromoViewModel`
3. You're using `Promo` but you probably meant `Promo.image`, also `Promo` needs to belong to the `BindingContext`

Comment: the problem is not in my flowlistview . but the Image Above flowlistview, i want to shows the latest image as a headline but i dont know how to bind it,  and why i write itemsource aswell because at first i dont know which one i should use but its work fine.

Comment: Is that `Image` in the same context as `Items` ? Don't use both, only use the `FlowItemsSource`

Comment: The ViewModel you're showing us, and the Xaml do not match in the slightest. Post your code that it's working.

Comment: no im using Promo as context, i will edit my question

Comment: `Promo` and `Items` must belong to the same `BindingContext`

Comment: can i use like Promo.image in my context ?

Comment: because my Promo its containt image, name and id and maybe thats why my Image not shows up ?

Comment: And if `Promo` belongs to the `BindingContext`