# Image not appearing on MAC. Images does appear on PC

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Please see the XAML code below:

```
    <Image Source="http://192.168.1.91:32786/api/Images/5c60f693-bef5-e088-a485-80ee7300c695"/>
```

When  run the Android Emulator on my Windows PC, then the image appears.  However when I run the Android emulator on my MAC, then the image does no appear.  Please note that I have tried multiple emulators on both mahnes and the result is the same.  Why is this?

So far I have tried:

1) Browsing to the image in the web browser, which works.
2) Launch the Android Emulator on a Windows PC and the image appears in the Android application.  It does not appear in the Android application when I launch the Android emulator from the Mac.  I am using the same emulator (Marshmellow on each PC).
3) I have tried different emulators on both machines and the results are the same.

Comment: firewall or any of a thousand networking related issues.  Have you done anything to try and debug it?

Comment: @Jason the image url runs on the mac, so if it was down to a firewall issue then I would expect to see it from windows rather than mac.

Comment: Using different API level emulators? As you have to configure `cleartextTrafficPermitted` in order to use `http`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55997456/4984832

Comment: @SushiHangover, thanks.  Is that specific to mac.  The image runs when the emulator is run on windows.

Comment: @w0051977 Is the emulator API-level image the same? Can you load the image in the emulator's browser? Does `logcat` show any errors?

Comment: are you running debug builds on both?  have you tried loading the url in the emulator's browser?

Comment: @Jason, I have just added what I have tried to the question.

Comment: Can you try to download that image from the url to see if there is any Exception throw?

Comment: @Jack Hua - MSFT, how would I know if an exception is thrown? The image is requested directly from the view.  Thanks.

Comment: I mean [download it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337487/how-to-download-image-from-url-and-save-it-to-a-local-sqlite-database).

Comment: @Jack Hua, it works if I do as you have suggested.

Comment: Then it should work, don't know what happened on your side when you use Source to load the image.

Comment: @Jack Hua, I am wandering if it could be down to what amirvenus says here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/119404/images-not-showing-in-xf-osx-project.  I don't have access to my MAC at the moment but will later.

Comment: Well, you can have a try later.

Comment: Does it work when deployed to a phone?